# Ada - timing problem when using ttyUSB device (FTDI chip)

Tags: serial-port, ada, timing

I have an odd problem with a simple Ada program that uses the "GNAT.Serial_Communications" package.

The program sends seven bytes (126, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 254) over the serial port device (8,N,1 @ 115200 Baud), and I have verified that this is performed correctly using a logic analyser connected directly to the serial port pins.

The strange thing is that there are two large gaps (varies between 0.6 milliseconds and 2.4 ms) between the first three bytes sent.  The rest of the bytes are sent at maximum speed as one would expect.  Each individual byte is perfectly formed and sent at the correct rate.  The idle time between bytes is the part that varies.  In other words the timing looks like this...

```
[126]..........(big gap)..........[1]..........(big gap)..........[0][0][0][0][254]
```

I have a C version of this program that does not exhibit this behaviour, all bytes are sent in a single burst with no gaps.

Equally, `cat`ting the same data directly into the serial port from Bash also does not have these big gaps between the first three bytes.

So it appears that there is some aspect of the Ada libraries / runtimes that introduces this variable delay in the middle of my byte stream.

For my project, this is a tolerable problem but I would like to try to find out why this is happening.

There is apparently no problem with reading bytes from the serial port, it receives everything correctly.

```vhdl
with Interfaces; use Interfaces;
with Ada.Text_IO; use Ada.Text_IO;
with Ada.Streams; use Ada.Streams;
with GNAT.Serial_Communications;

procedure Main is
   SP : GNAT.Serial_Communications.Serial_Port;

   In_Data : String (1 .. 6) := "~ddddS"; --  this string literal is illustrative only
   In_Buffer : Stream_Element_Array (1 .. 6);
   Length : Stream_Element_Offset;

   type PropIO_Octet is mod (2 ** 8);
   type PropIO_Packet_Data is array (1 .. 4) of PropIO_Octet;

   Packet_Start :         constant PropIO_Octet := 16#7E#;
   Packet_Escape_Marker : constant PropIO_Octet := 16#7D#;
   Packet_Escape_XOR :    constant PropIO_Octet := 16#20#;

   Command_Hard_Reset : constant PropIO_Octet := 16#00#;
   Command_Watchdog :   constant PropIO_Octet := 16#01#;


   procedure TX_Octet (Octet : in PropIO_Octet; Allow_Escape : in Boolean) is
      Out_Buffer : Stream_Element_Array (1 .. 1);
      Temp_Oct : PropIO_Octet := Octet;
   begin
      if Allow_Escape then
         if (Temp_Oct = Packet_Start) or (Temp_Oct = Packet_Escape_Marker) then
            Out_Buffer (Stream_Element_Offset (1)) := Character'Pos (Character'Val (Packet_Escape_Marker));

            GNAT.Serial_Communications.Write (SP, Out_Buffer);

            Temp_Oct := Temp_Oct xor Packet_Escape_XOR;
         end if;
      end if;

      Out_Buffer (Stream_Element_Offset (1))
        := Character'Pos (Character'Val (Temp_Oct));

      GNAT.Serial_Communications.Write (SP, Out_Buffer);
   end TX_Octet;


   procedure TX_Packet (
     Command : in PropIO_Octet;
     Data : in PropIO_Packet_Data
     ) is

      CS : PropIO_Octet := 16#00#;
   begin
      TX_Octet (Packet_Start, False);

      TX_Octet (Command, True);
      CS := CS xor Command;

      for D of Data loop
         TX_Octet (D, True);
         CS := CS xor D;
      end loop;

      CS := 16#FF# - CS;
      TX_Octet (CS, True);

   end TX_Packet;


begin
   GNAT.Serial_Communications.Open(SP, "/dev/ttyUSB0");

   GNAT.Serial_Communications.Set (
      Port      => SP,
      Rate      => GNAT.Serial_Communications.B115200,
      Bits      => GNAT.Serial_Communications.CS8,
      Stop_Bits => GNAT.Serial_Communications.One,
      Parity    => GNAT.Serial_Communications.None
      );

   for i in 1 .. 10 loop
      TX_Packet (Command_Watchdog, (0,0,0,0));
      delay 1.0;

      GNAT.Serial_Communications.Read (SP, In_Buffer, Length);

      for i in 1 .. Length loop
         In_Data (Integer (i)) := Character'Val (In_Buffer (i));
      end loop;

      Put_Line ("Response: " & In_Data (1 .. (Integer (Length))));
   end loop;

   GNAT.Serial_Communications.Close (SP);
end Main;
```

I'm running this code under Ubuntu 19.10 (latest updates) and Gnat 8.3.0.  The serial device connected via USB is a legitimate FTDI device.

Any ideas what might cause this?

Comment: You might want to try to first fill a stream buffer (array) with the complete packet data and then `Write` this buffer to the serial port in one go. The delay might be caused by the fact that you send the message byte-by-byte. The OS might not respond to the individual write requests immediately.

Comment: The baudrate only applies to the transmission of the bits that compose the character frame.  The timing of the frames is asynchronous; that is what the "A" in UART stands for.  The timing gaps you see between character frames indicates that the application did not "write" (actually request via syscall) the data fast enough to keep the UART busy transmitting.  The USB packet interface between the processor and UART adds an additional layer of inefficiency, and can exacerbate inefficient user code, i.e. byte-by-byte writes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not the actual answer to the question (the answer is already in the comments I guess), but just a hint regarding the example code. As the type `GNAT.Serial_Communications.Serial_Port` derives from `Ada.Streams.Root_Stream_Type`, you can also use the stream-oriented attributes `'Read` and `'Write` to read and write to the serial port. As an example:

**main.adb**

```
with Ada.Text_IO;
with GNAT.Serial_Communications;

procedure Main is

   package SC renames GNAT.Serial_Communications;

   type Byte is mod 2**8;
   type Byte_Array is array (Natural range <>) of Byte;

   package Byte_IO is
      new Ada.Text_IO.Modular_IO (Byte);

   Port_1 : aliased SC.Serial_Port;
   Port_2 : aliased SC.Serial_Port;

   End_Token : constant := 16#FF#;

   Buffer_Out : Byte_Array (0 .. 5) := (0, 1, 2, 3, 4, End_Token);
   Buffer_In  : Byte;

begin

   --  Open the ports.
   SC.Open (Port_1, "/dev/ttyS98");
   SC.Open (Port_2, "/dev/ttyS99");

   --  Write the byte array (packet) to port 1 in one go.
   Byte_Array'Write (Port_1'Access, Buffer_Out); 

   --  Read the byte array (packet) back from port 2, byte-by-byte.
   loop

      Byte'Read (Port_2'Access, Buffer_In);
      exit when Buffer_In = End_Token;

      Byte_IO.Put (Buffer_In);

   end loop;

   Ada.Text_IO.New_Line;

   --  Close the ports.
   SC.Close (Port_1);
   SC.Close (Port_2);

end Main;
```

The program can be tested by emulating two serial ports using `socat` (and pseudo-terminals, `pty`).

**console 1** (create the emulated serial ports)

```
$ sudo socat -d -d pty,raw,echo=0,link=/dev/ttyS98 pty,raw,echo=0,link=/dev/ttyS99
2020/01/14 20:23:04 socat[2540] N PTY is /dev/pts/1
2020/01/14 20:23:04 socat[2540] N PTY is /dev/pts/2
2020/01/14 20:23:04 socat[2540] N starting data transfer loop with FDs [5,5] and [7,7]
```

**console 2** (run the example program)

```
$ sudo ./main 
   0   1   2   3   4
```

*Note: `sudo` is required to create and access the emulated devices.*

Comment: Your code is a great deal easier to understand than what I managed to come up with, thank you for this, I'll retrofit some of this into my program.  I couldn't find any coherent documentation for the GNAT.Serial_Communications package so I had to basically open the "g-sercom.ads" file and try to figure it out the hard way, so I ended up with a mess.  Tell me, after how many years of Ada programming will I be able to stop being frustrated with the lack of docs? :)

Comment: Things will get easier :-). Most of the time I find myself reading through source code too. The GNAT code is documented quite well I think, although I must admit that it's easy to miss details if you're new to Ada. My best advice: just keep posting questions on Stack Overflow ;-).